# Xamarin MVVM Button binding

Tags: c#, xamarin, button, mvvm, binding

I'm stuck with this problem for already two days. I want to disable button after one click while using Data Binding. First my ViewModel checks if there are any free parking spaces available and then if there are 0 parking spaces available my Button is being disabled immediately after constructor is called. And if there are available parking spaces, after one press I want to decrement available parking spaces which is working fine, but my Button is still stays enabled, so how should I make it disabled after one press.
My ViewModel class:

```
public class SpacesPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int CurrentSpaces;
    public ICommand MyCommand { private set; get; }
    // BANDAU NAUJA DALYKA
    public ICommand myCommand
    {
        set
        {
            if(EmptySpaces == 0)
            {
                MyCommand.CanExecute(false);
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("myCommand"));
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return MyCommand;
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public ObservableCollection<Location> AllSpaces { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Location> allSpaces { get { return AllSpaces; } }
    public int EmptySpaces { get; set; }
    public int emptySpaces
    {
        set
        {
            if(EmptySpaces != value)
            {
                EmptySpaces = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("emptySpaces"));
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return EmptySpaces;
        }
    }

    public SpacesPageViewModel(string street)
    {
        var result = LocationsDb.Locations
            .Where(x => x.street == street)
            .Select(g => g.emptySpaces)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        MyCommand = new Command(() => 
        {
            foreach (var item in LocationsDb.Locations.Where(x => x.emptySpaces == EmptySpaces))
            {
                if (item.emptySpaces > 0)
                {
                    item.emptySpaces--;
                    emptySpaces = item.emptySpaces;
                    myCommand = MyCommand;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }, () => 
        {
            if (EmptySpaces == 0)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        });
        EmptySpaces = result;
        CurrentSpaces = result;
    }
}
```

My XAML:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="ParkingApp.Views.SpacesPage"
         ControlTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}"
         >
<ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="Reserve parking spot" 
               BackgroundColor="#e8e8e8" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
               HeightRequest="50" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
               FontSize="30"/>

        <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding emptySpaces}" FontSize="150" TextColor="Black" Margin="10"
               HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="2" Text="Free Spaces Left" TextColor="Black" FontSize="35" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
               HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="3" Margin="10" Text="RESERVE" Command="{Binding MyCommand}" FontSize="20"/>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: It's a bit hard because there is a lot of weird stuff going on that can result in unexpected behaviour. I would start with a basic tutorial on bindings and `INotifyPropertyChanged` (you've mixed up bindable property and backing fields).

Comment: You can use `IsEnable` property of button. Use Binding for it & handle the Boolean for it on button click. let me know if you need some help in that as well

Comment: I’m not really sure where should I put property IsEnable into my code. Should it be a separate function for handling the button?

Comment: @VidmantasTelksnys you can put `property IsEnable` into `SpacesPageViewModel`, then  also invoke `INotifyPropertyChanged`, you can checks if there are any free parking spaces available in SpacesPageViewModel's constructor, if yes, setting IsEnable as true, if no, setting `IsEnable` as false. If you click button to reduce free parking spaces, you can call function to check  if there are any free parking spaces available again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in the setter of myCommand Property.
The line  `MyCommand.CanExecute(false);` does not disable the button but calls the CanExecuteMethod with parameter false. I guess your intention was to call ChangeCanExecute() method, to notify that the command status could be changed. So replace this line with:

```
((Command) MyCommand)).ChangeCanExecute();
```